# Passing a global object back to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm teaching myself asp.net C# MVC and am not really understanding how to bring data back to the view.

All the tutorial examples are trivial i.e
1) Create a Model (Book)
2) In the controller you create a book object (and copy into a ViewModel) i.e Author and Title and a collection of Chapters.
3) Reference the View Model object in the view i.e @Model.Title etc.

However in my case, I have an object that is already created previously and I want to send that back to the view.

For example. Imagine that a library has a book created in controller1. (this is called book1 and then returned back to a view.

I have another controller (controller2) that will add a new Chapter to book1.

So the questions are:

a) Where is the best place to create book1 so that I can reference in all controllers ?
b) Once the book1 object is created, how does it get returned back to the View - It would seem from my examples that only objects created within a specific controller can be returned back to their associated view?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your controller should not cache the objects it creates. Let the database store the object and retrieve it again if you have a GET Edit usecase.
You do not want to remember state between requests (RESTful architecture).
This means that you have to send all data that an action requires as parameters.

So lets assume you have a BookController that has a CreateBook action.
This action should return the ID of the created Book in the database. 
(Or it returns a View where the ActionLinks to edit the book are initialized with the correct ID).
This Id has to be passed to all actions that edit an existing book.

For example, in the View that gets displayed after a book has been created:

```
@Model ExistingBookViewModel

@Html.ActionLink("Add chapter", "AddChapter", "Chapter", new { bookId = Model.Id })
```

Here, `ExistingBookViewModel.Id` is the ID of the created book and set in BookController.

Then your ChapterController can define the AddChapter Action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddChapter(long bookId) {
    var book = dbContext.Books.Find(bookId);
    var viewModel = new AddChapterViewModel {
        BookId = bookId,
        BookName = book.Name,
        ChapterName = string.Empty // to be provided by User in AddChapter view
        // ...
    };
    return View("AddChapter", viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddChapter(AddChapterViewModel postData) {
    var book = dbContext.Books.Find(postData.BookId);

    var newChapter = new Chapter {
        Name = postData.ChapterName,
        // ...
    };

    book.Chapters.Add(newChapter);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: That's a good answer in my opinion. Just one detail - you could return updated book model to View instead of HttpStatusCodeResult.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed response!

Answer (score 0):

a) I would keep the model separate from any controller file and reference it in any controller/view where it's needed by including the namespaces. This will keep the organized.

b) You can use the [Controller.View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx) method to pass whatever model you want to the View, but the view should define that model (example -`@model MyApp.Models.MyModel`) in order for it to use it. From there you can use bind the model to your view to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Create static variable in any class, it will be accessible in others classes.

But why not select object again? Performance is nice, but simple and bug-free algorithm is much more important.

If you want to cache database, think about caching results of sql statements:

```
string sql = "select ...";
string hash = "book_" + sql.GetHashCode();
Book b = null;
if (HttpRuntime.Cache[hash] != null)
{
     b = (Book)HttpRuntime.Cache[hash];
}
else
{
     b = SelectBookFromSql(sql);
     HttpRuntime.Cache[hash] = b;
}
```